# OpenLiberty - How to separate application logs from server logs and set the correct Log level

Tags: java, logging, configuration, open-liberty

I use SLF4J with Logback to log events in my application which is deployed on OpenLiberty. The current log output:

```
[INFO] [07/05/2023 00:07:53:743 CEST] 0000005a SystemOut     O   [ERROR] o.p.c.p.c.TextArrayConverter - ...
```

Because of that, all logs appears at the INFO level :

```
[INFO] [07/05/2023 00:36:53:483 CEST] 000000ab SystemOut     O   [ERROR] ...
[INFO] [07/05/2023 00:36:53:483 CEST] 000000ab SystemOut     O   [INFO] ...
[INFO] [07/05/2023 00:37:53:487 CEST] 000000ab SystemOut     O   [INFO] ...
```

However, I want the output to look like this :

```
[ERROR] o.p.c.p.c.TextArrayConverter - ...
```

**Which configuration should I use to have the desired output ? or at least show the correct severity in server logs ?**

I have no logging configuration in server.xml.

*bootstrap.properties*:

```
com.ibm.ws.logging.stackTraceSingleEntry=true
com.ibm.ws.logging.message.log.level=OFF
com.ibm.ws.logging.message.format=json
com.ibm.ws.logging.message.source=
com.ibm.ws.logging.trace.log.level=OFF
com.ibm.ws.logging.console.format=TBASIC
com.ibm.ws.logging.console.log.level=INFO
```

*logback.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <Pattern>
        [%level] %C{1} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I tried different bootstrap configurations but nothing worked. For exemple, I tried to output logs in JSON format by adding to the *bootstrap.properties* file :

```
com.ibm.ws.logging.apps.write.json=true
com.ibm.ws.logging.console.format=JSON
```

The output was :

```
{"message":"[ERROR] o.p.c.p.c.TextArrayConverter - ...","level":"SystemOut",...}
```

The level is not set correctly.

**EDIT:**

An answer was provided in this post: [Logback JUL appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472129/logback-jul-appender).

I did a similar thing by changing the SLF4J binding from Logback to JUL since OpenLiberty uses JUL.
Using JUL with SLF4J is described [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/logback/setting-up-slf4j/)